# nodejs module.js:340 throw err; using WebSocket-Node

Tags: node.js, module, runtime-error

im new to this , i installed the nodejs with the installer in windows.
then i installed the WebSocket-Node module with this command:
npm install websocket , looks like successful install .

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket/-/websocket-1.0.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket/-/websocket-1.0.8.tgz

> websocket@1.0.8 install D:\dev\html5\books\bumper\node_modules\websocket
> node install.js

[websocket v1.0.8] Attempting to compile native extensions.
[websocket v1.0.8] Native extension compilation successful!
websocket@1.0.8 node_modules\websocket
```

it installed the nodejs in this location :

> c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\

now i try to execute the server.js example from https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node
im getting this error:

```
D:\dev\html5\books\bumper>node server.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/websocket'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\dev\html5\books\bumper\server.js:3:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

also the module is installed in the project root did not in the nodejs dir , is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message it looks like the require line looks like this

```
var websocket = require('/path/to/websocket');
```

Once you've installed something with npm, you can use just the module name:

```
var websocket = require('websocket');
```