# Jasmine-reporters error in angularjs end to end test

Tags: angularjs, protractor, jasmine-node

I'm trying to integrate Jasmine reports with Angular end to end test. But while running the test I'm getting the following error(I even tried the same in windows based environement and got the same result),

```
in on prepare method
Error: Cannot find module 'jasmine-reporters'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at exports.config.onPrepare (/apps/opt/projects/pcp/workspace/pcp/modules/web/public/test/config/protractor-e2e-conf.js:18:6)
    at Runner.runFilenamesOrFns_ (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:64:9)
    at Runner.runTestPreparers (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:91:8)
    at runner.controlFlow.execute.then.jasmineNodeOpts (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/jasmine.js:39:12)
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1531:20)
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1396:8)
==== async task ====
run test preparers
    at Object.exports.run (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/frameworks/jasmine.js:38:24)
    at driverprovider_.setupEnv.then.then.then.testResult (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:233:28)
    at _fulfilled (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
    at flush (/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
```

I already added 'Jasmine-reporters' as npm install -g jasmine-reporters

also I can see the folder under,

/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/jasmine-reporters

My protractor config is as follows,

```
exports.config = {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://172.16.136.181:4444/wd/hub',

        specs: [
                '../e2e/*.js',
              ],

        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
        },

        baseUrl:'http://gdc-java64-13:9000',

        allScriptsTimeout: 96000,

        onPrepare: function() {

        require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter(null, true, true, 'testresults.e2e'));

        },


          jasmineNodeOpts: {
                // onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.
                onComplete: null,
                // If true, display spec names.
                isVerbose: false,
                // If true, print colors to the terminal.
                showColors: true,
                // If true, include stack traces in failures.
                includeStackTrace: true,
                // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
                defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
              }

};
```

Do anyone have any idea.

Thank You

Comment: Did you have several node installations ?

Comment: No only one configured in my bashrc as,PATH=<some more path values>:/apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/bin

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved after I set the NODE_PATH environment variable as,

export NODE_PATH = /apps/softwares/node-v0.10.28-linux-x86/lib/node_modules

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970290/nodejs-module-js340-error-cannot-find-module)

Comment: Same problem here configuring Team City to run Protractor tests on Windows Server 2012 R2. The path I had to use was: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules. Thanks! This solution worked fine for me